# Why is this question listed under the unanswered questions?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, unanswered-questions

In [Unanswered Questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) there is an answered question.
Why is it there? Can we get a fix, if this isn't intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Unanswered Questions section is explicitly "Questions with no **upvoted** answers". There is a tab available if you want to specifically look at ones without *any* answer (the `answers:0` search parameter also works for those who want to search in the unanswered bins).

The filter runs on the principle that a question that has no upvoted answers has no satisfactory answer - neither the question author, nor anyone else viewing the question, has found the answer useful so it probably isn't an answer to the question. So, equivalently, the question remains unanswered and needing of a good answer.

Comment: Ah. Thanks, that clears it up.